# JS regex name pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a little help. I want to create a regex pattern in order to validate names, it should contain  only letters (any type of letters, non European included), apostrophes, periods, dashes and whitespaces. Or, to put it in another flavor, the regex should not validate any numbers, [], {}, <> etc. Is there a way to to that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some examples of what you're trying to match as well as counterexamples would be good too.

Comment: Some people suggest that names should not be validated like that. Its very easy to miss some corner case and then ruin the day of some costumer with a strange name.

Comment: I 'm a noob to regex, so I tried this: /^[a-zA-Z]|\s*$/.test(value)

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\w|\s|[\.\'-])+/
```

But that's not enough, I guess. Surely we must consider that an apostrophe can not be in the beginning, that several dashes can not follow in a row, etc.

You need a more precise definition of the *name*.

Comment: This will match numbers that is not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The Regex you pasted is flawed, it should be

```
^([a-zA-Z]|\s)*$
```

Notice the extra parenthesis

Also, You were on the right track but just put all allowed characters in the character class [] :

```
^([-\w'.\s])*$
```

a-zA-Z was replaced by the short hand character class for words \w

Add allowed characters as needed

Comment: Notice that to add - to a character class you can just add it in the beginning otherwise it will get its special meaning as in a-z. An excellent roundup can be found at http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: This will not match `Jean-François`